# don't know how to start this class for encrypting

Tags: java, encryption

I am given this class as a skeleton example for encrypting/decrypting but i have no clue how to start this, i am still new to java and i really need help. it supposed to have a simple encrypting algorithim and this class is supposed to have 3 other subclasses  each in a separate file which i have done already

```
import java.io.IOException;
public abstract class CryptStream
{
    protected StreamPair streams;
    /** Constructor 
     * @param theStreams a constructed StreamPair Instance
     */
    public CryptStream(StreamPair theStreams)
    {
    }
    /** Encrypt data in the byte array
     * @param data - the data to encrypt
     * @param len - how many bytes in the array to encrypt
     * @return a byte array with data encrypted. length may not be equal to
     * input
     */
    abstract protected byte [] cryptData( byte [] data, int len); 
    /** Decrypt data in the byte array
     * @param data - the data to decrypt
     * @param len - how many bytes in the array to decrypt
     * @return a byte array with data decrypted. length may not be equal to
     * input
     */
    abstract protected byte [] decryptData( byte [] data,int len);
    /** encrypt the input stream, and write to the output stream of 
     * of the StreamPair 
    *  @return number of bytes in output stream
    */
    public final int encrypt()
    {
        return 0; 
    }
    /** decrypt the input stream, and write to the output stream of 
     * of the StreamPair 
    *  @return number of bytes in output stream
    */
    public final int decrypt()
    {
        return 0; 
    }

}
```

Comment: This is an `abstract class`. You can only use a `class` that is not abstract to create objects from. If there is none implemented, then you have to do it yourself.

Comment: Basically, the idea is to open the streams, get data from the input stream, call the appropriate abstract crypt/decrypt method, then write the output to the output stream.

Comment: @ArtjomB., Hotfin already wrote the subclasses that implement cryptData / decryptData. This is about getting the data into and out of the streams.

Comment: AustinMullins is correct, i have the subclasses for them i just dont know how to get the data into/out of the streams

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to design your classes similar to `InputStreamReader`/`InputStreamWriter`:

For reading encrypted stream extends `java.io.Reader` class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Reader;

public class EncryptedStreamReader extends Reader {
    private final InputStream in;
    private final String key;

    public EncryptedStreamReader(final InputStream in, final String key) {
        this.in = in;
        this.key = key;
    }

    @Override
    public int read(final char[] cbuf, final int off, final int len) throws IOException {
        //TODO all magic here
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Such approach have several pros:

- Following common java approaches for io sub-system design
- Can be used without any additional code in places that works with Reader (actually it's just a good example of polymorphism)